# Returning undefined from fetch api inside getStaticProps

Tags: next.js

I'm try to fetch users from jsonplaceholder api and render a lista with map, but neither fetch api nor axios are able to fetch data from within getStaticProps, and getStaticProps is also not passing the props to the component even though be hardcoded data.

//pages/UsersList.js

```
const UsersList = ({ users }) => {
  console.log(users);

  return <div>Users</div>;
};

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/');
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);

  return {
    props: {
      users: data,
    },
  };
};

export default UsersList;
```

//pages/index.js

```
import UsersList from './UsersList';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <UsersList />
    </div>
  );
}
```

//pages/_app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem: as I was creating the UsersList in pages and using it as a component in index.js, the component was being rendered but getStaticProps is not called on another page, only getStaticProps from index.js would be called, which in this case did not exist.

//components/UsersList.js

```
const UsersList = ({ users }) => {
  console.log(users);

  return <div>Users</div>;
};

export default UsersList;
```

//pages/index.js

```
import UsersList from './UsersList';

export default function Home({ users }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <UsersList users={users}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/');
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);

  return {
    props: {
      users: data,
    },
  };
};
```

//pages/_app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: nice bro my code now works too

Answer (score 0):

creating UserList.js inside the pages folder makes it a separate web page in your app, You can't import UserList as a react component and use it in index.js. The fetched data can be seen if you go to http://localhost:3000/UsersList page.